# Air sealing vent baffles in cathedral ceiling

Tags: insulation, roofing

I am reroofing my house.  I am taking the opportunity to pull up the decking above the cathedral ceiling and adding air baffles to help cool the roof and reduce ice dams.

In order to accomplish this, I am using 1 inch rigid foam board pushed down two inches with spacers between board and roof deck.  I am using the foam board to regain some of the reduced r value from compressing the fiberglass insulation, but also for the rigidity to help compress the fiberglass.

Should I air seal all the seams between sheets of foam board, or leave them open to allow moisture in the fiberglass a path to escape?  The fiberglass is foil backed with the foil against the ceiling.  Ceiling is tongue and groove wood, so probably pretty permeable.

Comment: Is there a vapor barrier at ceiling level?

Comment: Have you considered using vents made for a cathedral roof? I couldn't find the link to the exact product I used (pink foam, but the same idea), but thses ought to do the trick: https://www.sprayfoamsys.com/product/accuvent-acbp18425-15-x-48-16-o-c-flame-retardant-pvc-cathedral-ceiling-vent-50-pack/?gclid=EAIaIQobChMI07bbuZnE5AIVw5-zCh0JRQXSEAkYBCABEgLvafD_BwE

Comment: Vapor barrier at ceiling is foil faced fiberglass insulation, which is probably not terribly air tight.

Comment: if those accuvent baffles are anything like the baffles locally available at the box stores, they will be tough to install because they are pretty flimsy.

Comment: @ nothingtoseehere, that really should have been an answer the op may not have liked it but they are energystar listed and provide an answer , the only one offered, this could help some one else make it an answer and let me know and I will up vote.